# Error handling on snoostorm / snoowrap (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, bots, reddit

I'm working on a Reddit bot running on NodeJS and based on snoostorm and snoowrap but I'm having trouble handling errors.

I would like to catch any error occured when trying to access the `comment` object (I.E. to reply to it). Such errors would be both networking ones (401, 503) and Reddit ones (THREAD_LOCKED, RATELIMIT, SOMETHING_IS_BROKEN).

I have tried using the following try/catch, both inside and outside the `stream.on()` callback but nothing seems to change. Here's the code.

```
const r = new Snoowrap({
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    username: process.env.REDDIT_USER,
    password: process.env.REDDIT_PASS
});

const stream = new CommentStream(r, {
    subreddit: 'testingground4bots',
    results: 1
});


stream.on('item', comment => {
    try {
        comment.reply('This is a test')
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('An error occurred', e)
    }
})
```

No suppose the receiver of that message blocked my bot. What I would get is a `SOMETHING_IS_BROKEN` error. I'm interested in handling such an error to be able to react accordingly.

The developer of snoostorm [says the following](https://github.com/MayorMonty/Snoostorm/issues/23), regarding error handling:

> Events should bubble up through the call stack, and as such `try/catch` or promise `.catch()` is going to be your best bet. Currently I'm not exposing the raw requests on the `Poll` parent class, but I imagine that could be a feature in the future.

Yet I had no luck with try/catch and I get TypeErrors when I try to `comment.catch()`, possibly because the promise has already been fulfilled when it reaches my code. I've tried reaching out to the developer via an issue on GitHub but I haven't received an answer after more than a month since I opened it.

Here's how the error's call stack looks like in the console:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: SOMETHING_IS_BROKEN,Something is broken, please try again later.,parent
    at [...]\node_modules\snoowrap\dist\helpers.js:84:11
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.finallyHandler ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\finally.js:57:23)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.tryCatcher ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
    at Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] ([...]\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21)
```

## EDIT: August 2022

The Snoostorm developer [commented](https://github.com/MayorMonty/Snoostorm/issues/58):

> currently there is no way for you to handle exceptions encountered, but it wouldn't be too difficult to add. I will add it to my todo list :-)

Though I wouldn't raise my hopes too high. That repository isn't very active and I quite frankly don't expect this to ever get fixed. For the time being it's nothing tragic for my bot, even in case of errors it doesn't crash and that's good enough for me.
Sorry for anyone else dealing with this issue, I'm afraid this is all I can do to help you.

Comment: Did you manage to figure something out or are you still stuck?

Comment: I had kinda forgotten about this question. Yes I have an update and no, it's nothing good. I'll update my question.